# When does editing a question *not* bump it to the top?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I've got an older (about a month old) question that I just made a significant update to, but on all of the lists I see it on, it's still showing the month-old date.

Of course, I understand the potential for abuse, and am not really advocating anything get changed.

I'm just trying to understand if there are certain conditions in which the post will *not* get bumped?

Here is the question in... umm, question: [How to use HandleError with model state errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454525/how-to-use-handleerror-with-model-state-errors)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Commenting won't bump the post, afaik.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *did* bump it. For ease, I picked the lowest frequency tag and picked the Active sort, which will tell us the most recently updated stuff. It is possible that you were just looking at a bunch of cached pages (as in, the results were cached, not necessarily your browser view).

[image: Active Sort, question is on top dated 47 minutes ago]

I'm not aware that anything exists to prevent bumping on the active sort (as that defeats its purpose). However on the *front page*, for non-Stack Overflow sites on the network, questions with low enough score will not appear to be bumped by an edit (as they are not shown on the front page if they are highly downvoted).

Comment: This of course assumes the user is looking at the active sort, not the newest sort. (:

Comment: I was looking at the Intersting (default) sort, which I believe (in some cases) includes recently updated questions, not just newly created or newly answered.  Maybe I'm mistaking though?

Comment: @Jerad Stack Overflow's "Interesting" figures in a lot of things. I couldn't tell you why your question would or would not show up, because I'm not privvy to the complete algorithm. But, I do know that tag preferences, score, and time all figure into it in different ways.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 2):

The question will not be bumped if the change was made by the same user who made the previous change, and they made it within 5 minutes of the last revision.